# How to LEFT JOIN with tables without association depending on column value

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

The objective is to implement the next SQL using JPA:

```
SELECT f.id as id, f.entity_name as entity_name, f.entity_id as entity_id,
   CASE f.entity_name
      WHEN 'active-substance' then a.name
      WHEN 'outcome' then o.name
      WHEN 'symptom' then s.name
      WHEN 'therapeutic-regime' then t.name
   END as entity_description
FROM feedback f
LEFT JOIN active_substance a ON f.entity_name = 'active-substance' AND f.entity_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN outcome o ON f.entity_name = 'outcome' AND f.entity_id = o.id
LEFT JOIN symptom s ON f.entity_name = 'symptom' AND f.entity_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN therapeutic_regime t ON f.entity_name = 'therapeutic-regime' AND f.entity_id = t.id
```

Entity Feedback

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "feedback")
public class Feedback {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "entity_name", nullable = false)
    private EntityFeedback entityName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "entity_id", nullable = false)
    private Long entityId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    //@Where("entity_name = 'active-substance'")
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private ActiveSubstance activeSubstance;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    //@Where(clause = "entity_name = 'outcome'")
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private Outcome outcome;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    //@Where(clause = "entity_name = 'symptom'")
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "feedback" }, allowSetters = true)
    private Symptom symptom;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    //@Where(clause = "entity_name = 'therapeutic-regime'")
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "feedback" }, allowSetters = true)
    private TherapeuticRegime therapeuticRegime;

...
```

The @Where is not used in the query

How can I condition the LEFT JOIN depending on the column entity_name value?

Checked on Vlad Mihalcea blog but did not found any similar case.

Comment: @VladMihalcea Do you have any clue?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use HQL which is very similar to the SQL example you gave:

```
SELECT f.id as id, f.entityName, f.entityId,
   CASE f.entityName 
      WHEN 'active-substance' then a.name
      WHEN 'outcome' then o.name
      WHEN 'symptom' then s.name
      WHEN 'therapeutic-regime' then t.name
   END as entity_description
FROM Feedback f
LEFT JOIN ActiveSubstance a ON f.entityName = 'active-substance' AND f.entityId = a.id
LEFT JOIN Outcome o ON f.entityName = 'outcome' AND f.entityId = o.id
LEFT JOIN Symptom s ON f.entityName = 'symptom' AND f.entityId = s.id
LEFT JOIN TherapeuticRegime t ON f.entityName = 'therapeutic-regime' AND f.entityId = t.id
```